# How to access profile model filename field to display each users profile picture

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

Hi all I am trying to access the profile picture filename for each individual user as and when they are logged into the system. I have a 'profiles' table and I need to make this available in my default.ctp view file as I am trying to load profile images.

I currently use the $current_user variable set in my appController's beforefilter to access the 'users' in the form $current_user['filename']. My user and profile relationships have been set in my models accordingly. If anyone could help I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

My AppController's beforeFilter declaration:

```
$this->loadModel('Profile');
    $profiles = $this->Profile->find('all');
    $this->set('profiles', $profiles);
```

My default.ctp view file code attempt:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('/uploads/profile/filename/thumb/small/'.$profile['filename']); ?>
```

Current code:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('/uploads/profile/filename/thumb/small/'.$current_user['filename']); ?>
```

I need to be able to access the current user's profile models filename field in order to display their picture which has already been saved to the filename field. It will be called as the user logs in and I want to display this users profile picture.

In the default.ctp view Iam using the code below but I need to adapt it for each individual users profile picture.

```
foreach($profiles as $profile) : 
    echo $current_user['Profile']['filename'];
endforeach
```

;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joshua, first of all, instead of posting again try keeping your thread all together (you can edit your post, and this helps others who are searching for the same answer).

[How to make a Model available in a View Cakephp 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13792826/1867941)

Again, I'd recommend doing this with an view element and requestAction, but as you didn't accept that answer last time, I'll work with what you are doing here:

If the user is already authenticated, you should have some information about them that you can check in:

```
 $this->Auth->User();
```

So, I'd re-work your code as follows:

```
$this->loadModel('Profile');
$user_id = $this->Auth->User('id');
$profile = $this->Profile->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('Profile.user_id'=>$user_id), 'fields'=>array('filename'));
$this->set(compact('profile'));
```

Now in your default.ctp file you should be able to call the following:

```
echo $this->Html->image('/uploads/profile/filename/thumb/small/'.$profile['Porfile']['filename']);
```

Comment: Thanks shoesole I will remember this in future. I have tested your approach and it works like a charm. Thanks.